# Label rendering issue in TableCell

Tags: javafx

I am encountering an issue with rendering a Label in TableCell. The Label flickers when the TableCell gets an update. This happens if I wrap the Label in a Pane and set it as graphic to the cell.

On the other hand, if I set the Label directly as the graphic(without wrapper), then it doesn't show the flickering effect.

Do any of you have any idea why this happens.

Below is a quick demo that showcases the flickering effect of the Label. You can uncomment the other line and can see the flickering does not happen. The issue happens on both JavaFX8 and JavaFX20

**When wrapped with StackPane (flickering):**

[image]

*(some frames might be skipped in gif, but the flickering happens on every update)*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class LabelRenderingInCell_Demo extends Application {

    class Person {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(final String n) {
            setName(n);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(final String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name.get();
        }
    }

    private int count = 1;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person("Name");
        final ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.add(person);

        final TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        final TableColumn<Person, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        col.setPrefWidth(150);
        col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().nameProperty());
        col.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, String> call(final TableColumn<Person, String> param) {
                return new TableCell<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(null);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setGraphic(new StackPane(new Label(item)));
                            // Uncomment the below code for no flickering
                           // setGraphic(new Label(item));
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        tableView.setItems(items);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Button btn = new Button("Update");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            person.setName("Name " + count++);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(btn, tableView));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Label In TableCell");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The content of is very dynamic based on the value associated with the property. It can be combination of different colored labels with some images as well

[image]

**Update #2:**
Based on the suggestions in the comments, I changed my code to reuse the labels or atleast maintain a pool of Labels. But I still see the flickering everytime a new Label is added to cell.

Below is a quick modified demo with the logic. I am using a pool of 5 Labels that needs to be displayed based on the grade. Each Label will have its own styling, interactions, icons etc. So using only 1 Label for all grades will make things too messy here.

The Label flickers everytime a new grade Label is generated and added. For testing purpose included a refresh button that generates a new cell for checking the cycle again. *(You may not see the flicker in the below gif if the frames gets skipped, but you can notice when running the application)*

**It may look like it is just a blink. When the behavior is not systematic, it looks a bit odd/worse when seen on larger scale.**

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LabelRenderingInCell_Demo extends Application {

    class Person {
        private final ObjectProperty<Integer> score = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0);

        public ObjectProperty<Integer> scoreProperty() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(final int score) {
            this.score.set(score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person();
        final ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.add(person);

        final TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        final TableColumn<Person, Integer> col = new TableColumn<>("Grade");
        col.setPrefWidth(150);
        col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().scoreProperty());
        col.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, Integer> call(final TableColumn<Person, Integer> param) {
                return new TableCell<>() {
                    private Map<String, Label> labelPool = new HashMap<>();
                    private HBox pane = new HBox();

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(final Integer item, final boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(null);
                        if (item != null) {
                            pane.getChildren().clear();
                            Label label = getLabel(item);
                            label.setText(buildGrade(item) + "(" + item + ")");
                            pane.getChildren().addAll(label);
                            setGraphic(pane);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }

                    private String buildGrade(int score) {
                        if (score < 3) {
                            return "Poor";
                        } else if (score < 5) {
                            return "Average";
                        } else if (score < 7) {
                            return "Good";
                        } else if (score < 9) {
                            return "Better";
                        } else {
                            return "Excellent";
                        }
                    }

                    private Label getLabel(int score) {
                        String grade = buildGrade(score);
                        Label lbl = labelPool.get(grade);
                        if (lbl == null) {
                            System.out.println("Cell-"+this.hashCode() + " ::  New label created.... " + grade);
                            lbl = new Label(grade + "(" + score + ")");
                            // Add other styling and interactions based on the grade
                            labelPool.put(grade, lbl);
                        }
                        return lbl;
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        tableView.setItems(items);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        Button btn = new Button("Update Score");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            person.setScore(rnd.nextInt(11));
        });

        Button refresh = new Button("Refresh Table to start from scratch");
        refresh.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            tableView.refresh();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(btn, refresh, tableView);
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Label In TableCell");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: might be unrelated (currently no time to check, sry), but: __never-ever__ create nodes in updateItem (as you should know :)). Curious: why the different version tags? If you don't see any version specifics, javafx alone should suffice.

Comment: I have a complex requirement which I need to combine different labels with different styles in grid form and set as graphic o table cell. So I cannot use a single Label instance on TableCell level and reuse that.

Comment: There's no reason why you can't create all the nodes you need on creation of the cell, and then configure them and set the required node as the graphic in `updateItem()`.

Comment: to put it more clearly: whatever the problem/requirement, you __must not__ create nodes in updateItem. Just take that as an impenetrable wall, no way to get through it. If you insist on doing it anyway and take an atom bomb to crush the wall, be prepared for fallout that will kill you ;)

Comment: aside: Person in the updated example returns a new instance of the object property wrapper on every call - should return the same :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that.. :) Was trying something else and forgot to refactor it. Corrected now.

Comment: Am I missing something? You call `getLabel` inside of `updateItem`, and `getLabel` creates a new `Label` every time it is called. You are essentially doing the same thing you were originally doing. You have just moved the label creation inside a method that's inside of `updateItem`.

Comment: @SedJ601 the `getLabel` method creates a Label if it not finds in the grade pool. So pretty much it can create max of 5 Labels (for each grade) and reuse them.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that you do not want to ever create a `Node` in `updateItem`.

Comment: I doubt it is not about creating a Node in updateItem. Lets say if I create 5 Labels on cell level (outside updateItem).. you can still see the issue, every time i switch the Labels.

Comment: I did not see an issue in my updated version of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create node instances in the `updateItem()` method. This method may be called frequently and is not designed for "heavy" operations such as creating UI nodes.

Instead, create any nodes you *might* need at the creation time of the cell. Then use the `updateItem()` method solely to configure those nodes and choose which to display, as necessary.

Here is an example cell factory which switches nodes on each button click, without any flicker:

```
    col.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Person, String> call(final TableColumn<Person, String> param) {
            return new TableCell<>() {

                private final Label label = new Label();
                private final StackPane even = new StackPane();
                private final StackPane odd = new StackPane();
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(null);
                    if (item != null) {
                        StackPane graphic ;
                        String[] tokens = item.split(" ");
                        int value = tokens.length == 2 ? Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) : 0;
                        graphic = value % 2 == 0 ? even : odd ;
                        even.getChildren().clear();
                        odd.getChildren().clear();
                        graphic.getChildren().add(label);
                        label.setText(item);
                        setGraphic(graphic);
                        // Uncomment the below code for no flickering
                        // setGraphic(new Label(item));
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely reconsider to change my logic accordingly. I updated the question with some quick info of how the data will be in the cell.

Comment: My main question is how come it flickers when wrapped with a Pane but doesnt when set directly. (In both cases i am creating new Labels)

Comment: _how come it flickers when wrapped with a Pane but doesnt when set directly_ that's an academic question, IMO: the former is as wrong as the latter, side-effects unpredictable which includes might-have-or-not-have-any ;) If you really have time and interest in finding the difference, you can dig deep into the mechanism of cell re-use.

Comment: @SaiDandem *"how come it flickers when wrapped with a Pane but doesnt when set directly"*. As pointed out in another comment, in both cases you are using the API in a way in which it's not intended to be used.

Comment: @SaiDandem Your cell could, if needed, maintain a cache of labels, image views, etc. In `updateItem()` retrieve nodes from the cache and configure them, creating new nodes as infrequently as possible.

Comment: @James_D I tried your suggestion of using a label pool to reuse the labels. But the Label still flickers for every new label. Updated my question with a new demo to demonstrate this.

Comment: hmm .. can reproduce: the very first showing of a new label in the cell hierarchy shows such flicker (thanks for the updated example :) No idea why or how to fix - could be applycss jumping in somehow (wild guessing only)

Comment: seems to be table specific (a quick check for ListView doesn't show the flicker, didn't try Tree)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be really a nasty problem:

- multiple nodes of which only a single one is added at any time
- added deeper down the cell hierarchy
- switching them out is done in updateItem

The very first time such a switched-in node is showing, it flickers - doesn't happen if switched again. Creating all nodes up front doesn't seem to help.

What does help (not formally tested, beware!) is to add the cell

- build all nodes up front
- have a listener on the tableView property, when triggered with tableView != null and its skin != null
- add all nodes into the pane and add the pane to the table
- cleanup again, probably need to remove the listener again

in code (note that the contentDisplay isn't really important, just something I prefer to do when it's graphic only :)

```
col.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<Person, Integer> call(final TableColumn<Person, Integer> param) {
        return new TableCell<>() {
            private Map<String, Label> labelPool = new HashMap<>();
            private HBox pane = new HBox();

            private ChangeListener<TableView<?>> tableListener;

            {
                buildPool();
                setGraphic(pane);
                setText("");
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

                tableListener = (src, ov, nv) -> {
                    if (nv != null) {
                        System.out.println(nv.getSkin());
                        if (nv.getSkin() != null) {
                            pane.getChildren().addAll(labelPool.values());
                            ((TableViewSkin<?>) nv.getSkin()).getChildren().add(this);
                            pane.getChildren().clear();
                        }
                    }
                };
                tableViewProperty().addListener(tableListener);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(final Integer item, final boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    Label label = getLabel(item);
                    label.setText(buildGrade(item) + "(" + item + ")");
                    pane.getChildren().setAll(label);
                } else {
                    pane.getChildren().clear();
                }
            }

            private void buildPool() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    getLabel(i);
                }
            }
            private String buildGrade(int score) {
                if (score < 3) {
                    return "Poor";
                } else if (score < 5) {
                    return "Average";
                } else if (score < 7) {
                    return "Good";
                } else if (score < 9) {
                    return "Better";
                } else {
                    return "Excellent";
                }
            }

            private Label getLabel(int score) {
                String grade = buildGrade(score);
                Label lbl = labelPool.get(grade);
                if (lbl == null) {
                    System.out.println("Cell-"+this.hashCode() + " ::  New label created.... " + grade);
                    lbl = new Label(grade + "(" + score + ")");
                    // Add other styling and interactions based on the grade
                    labelPool.put(grade, lbl);
                }
                return lbl;
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the providing an alternate solution. If I do have issues with my current solution, I will definitely consider this :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer based on your updated code. All the cell nodes should be created where you see `//Create all Cell Node Here!`.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class App extends Application {

    class Person {
        private final ObjectProperty<Integer> score = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0);

        public ObjectProperty<Integer> scoreProperty() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(final int score) {
            this.score.set(score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person();
        final ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.add(person);

        final TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        final TableColumn<Person, Integer> col = new TableColumn<>("Grade");
        col.setPrefWidth(150);
        col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().scoreProperty());
        col.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, Integer> call(final TableColumn<Person, Integer> param) {
                return new TableCell<>() {
                    //Create all Cell Node Here!
                    final Label lblOne = new Label();
                    final Label lblTwo = new Label();
                    final Label lblThree = new Label();
                    
                    final HBox hbViewRoot = new HBox(lblOne, lblTwo, lblThree);
                    
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(final Integer item, final boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(null);
                        if (item != null) {                            
                            lblOne.setText(buildGrade(item).substring(0, 1));
                            lblOne.setTextFill(getLabelColor());
                            lblTwo.setText(buildGrade(item).substring(1, 2));
                            lblTwo.setTextFill(getLabelColor());
                            lblThree.setText(buildGrade(item).substring(2, 3));
                            lblThree.setTextFill(getLabelColor());
                            setGraphic(hbViewRoot);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }

                    private String buildGrade(int score) {
                        if (score < 3) {
                            return "Poor";
                        } else if (score < 5) {
                            return "Average";
                        } else if (score < 7) {
                            return "Good";
                        } else if (score < 9) {
                            return "Better";
                        } else {
                            return "Excellent";
                        }
                    }
                    
                    private Color getLabelColor()
                    {         
                        int score = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(9);
                        
                        if (score < 3) {
                            return Color.RED;
                        } else if (score < 5) {
                            return Color.ORANGE;
                        } else if (score < 7) {
                            return Color.GREY;
                        } else if (score < 9) {
                            return Color.BLACK;
                        } else {
                            return Color.GREEN;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        tableView.setItems(items);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        Button btn = new Button("Update Score");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            person.setScore(rnd.nextInt(11));
        });

        Button refresh = new Button("Refresh Table to start from scratch");
        refresh.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            tableView.refresh();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(btn, refresh, tableView);
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Label In TableCell");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I already mentioned in the question update 2, that `Each Label will have its own styling, interactions, icons etc. So using only 1 Label for all grades will make things too messy here.`

Comment: On the other hand, even if create 5 Labels at `//Create all Cell Node Here!`, the issue still exists

Comment: If you use one or 20 `Labels`, they should all be created in the same space. That is your issue. How you structure your code in `updateItem` is separate from that and can be done in many ways.

Comment: this doesn't seem to help if there are multiple labels of which only a single one is added at any time - the problem seems to be the very first showing of a label

Comment: I strongly believe that creating all nodes at the same space or by lazy loading doesnt make a difference. Because the Label skin is generated only when rendered in scenegraph. And when i switch label the flicker happens.

Comment: Don't switch `Labels`. Set up your view and change your nodes' properties in `updateItem`.

Comment: Is it that you are saying to maintain only one label and update its styling, events, tooltips etc in updateItem based on grade?

Comment: I am saying create a view that meets your demands and use updateitems to update the properties of the nodes in your view.

Comment: I updated my code to have more than one label. I don't see any flickering. I created a view that has an HBox as its root node, and I updated the label's properties in `udpateItem`.

Comment: modifications of the hierarchy under the cell (particularly for the tableCell which is contained in a tableRow which is .. not nicely implemented ;) are tricky - they should work, though (and do f.i. in a ListView). The options might not be entirely nice: forcing  internal configuration by adding the hierarchy once before showing might be one (as done in my answer), another might be to go with a complex single pane (as suggested here) and configure that without modifying the tree too much. Afair, skin internals are doing the former at places ..

Comment: @SedJ601 yeah, all fine if the hierarchy isn't changed :) Which might or not be possible in RL ..

Comment: @SaiDandem, I would create the `ToolTips` and the `Eventhandlers` with the other `Nodes`. I would set them in `updateItem` if possible.

Comment: @SedJ601 I have never thought of the this view approach. Will give a try and see how it will fit to my current implementation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the question, the issue is not happening if I set the Label as direct graphic to the cell. So I started investigation to see what/where is the difference in work flow between

- `Label` as direct graphic to cell
- `Label` wrapped with `Pane` and the `Pane` as graphic to cell

One thing I noticed is, in the first case, the skin of the `Label` is instantly created as soon as it is set as graphic.

But in the second case, the skin is getting created in the next pulse. In other words, the `Label` is rendered in one pulse and the skin is generated in another pulse.

Skin is responsible for creating children (`LabeledText`) of Label. As there is a delay in creating skin (pulse gap), there is delay in showing the children. Which is causing the flicker effect.

To confirm this, I included a `preLayoutPulseListener` after setting the graphic. This listener will print the state of the `Label` at the start of the next pulse.

```
final Runnable startOfNextPulse = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Remove the listener after first run, as we don't want to bang the console with prints ;)
        getScene().removePreLayoutPulseListener(this);
        System.out.println(getCellCode() + " :: At start of pulse :: " + label.getText() + ", parent: " + label.getParent() + ", skin: " + label.getSkin() + ", children: " + label.getChildrenUnmodifiable().size());
        System.out.println(""); // Set debug point here
    }
};
if (getScene() != null) {
    getScene().addPreLayoutPulseListener(startOfNextPulse);
}
```

Below is the difference in logs :

**When `Label` as direct graphic to cell**

```
Cell-380181482 ::  New label created.... Good
Cell-380181482 :: Skin created for the label : Good
Cell-380181482 :: At start of pulse :: Good(6), parent: LabelRenderingInCell_Demo$1$1[id=null, styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-cell table-column]'null', skin: javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin@3518df5c, children: 1
```

**When `Label` wrapped with `Pane` and the `Pane` as graphic to cell**

```
Cell-1394753670 ::  New label created.... Good
Cell-1394753670 :: At start of pulse :: Good(5), parent: HBox@7e8529ed, skin: null, children: 0
Cell-1394753670 :: Skin created for the label : Good
```

From the above, in the first case, you can notice that the skin is created instantly and by the start of next pulse, the Label has skin and children.

Where as in the second case, the Label is in the scenegraph, but it has no skin and children.

If I keep a debug point in the listener to check the scenegraph state (visual state), below is the finding:

[image]

**Solution (at this stage for me):**

It is quite clear that for every new Label, there is a delay in skin creation. After setting the graphic, if I ensure to call `applyCss()` for the Label when the skin is not present, the issue is fixed :).

I sincerely thank you all for taking time and looking into the issue and providing valuable suggestions/approaches :-) . Please do let me know if this fix has any known unwanted issues.

Below is the full code, with the fix and the listener(for ref). You can check the issue by commenting the line `applyCss()`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LabelRenderingInCell_Demo extends Application {

    class Person {
        private final ObjectProperty<Integer> score = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0);

        public ObjectProperty<Integer> scoreProperty() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(final int score) {
            this.score.set(score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person();
        final ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.add(person);

        final TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        final TableColumn<Person, Integer> col = new TableColumn<>("Grade");
        col.setPrefWidth(150);
        col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().scoreProperty());
        col.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, Integer> call(final TableColumn<Person, Integer> param) {
                return new TableCell<>() {
                    private Map<String, Label> labelPool = new HashMap<>();
                    private HBox pane = new HBox();

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(final Integer item, final boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(null);
                        if (item != null) {
                            pane.getChildren().clear();
                            Label label = getLabel(item);
                            pane.getChildren().addAll(label);
                            setGraphic(pane);
                            
                            // SOLUTION TO THE ISSUE
                            if (label.getSkin() == null) {
                                label.applyCss();
                            }

                            // For debugging Purpose
                            final Runnable startOfNextPulse = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // Remove the listener after first run, as we don't want to bang the console with prints ;)
                                    getScene().removePreLayoutPulseListener(this);
                                    System.out.println(getCellCode() + " :: At start of pulse :: " + label.getText() + ", parent: " + label.getParent() + ", skin: " + label.getSkin() + ", children: " + label.getChildrenUnmodifiable().size());
                                    System.out.println(""); // Set debug point here
                                }
                            };
                            if (getScene() != null) {
                                getScene().addPreLayoutPulseListener(startOfNextPulse);
                            }
                            // End debugging
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }

                    private String buildGrade(int score) {
                        if (score < 3) {
                            return "Poor";
                        } else if (score < 5) {
                            return "Average";
                        } else if (score < 7) {
                            return "Good";
                        } else if (score < 9) {
                            return "Better";
                        } else {
                            return "Excellent";
                        }
                    }

                    private Label getLabel(int score) {
                        String grade = buildGrade(score);
                        Label lbl = labelPool.get(grade);
                        if (lbl == null) {
                            System.out.println("\n" + getCellCode() + " ::  New label created.... " + grade);
                            lbl = new Label(grade + "(" + score + ")");
                            lbl.setStyle("-fx-font-size:16;");
                            // Add other styling and interactions based on the score
                            lbl.skinProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
                                System.out.println(getCellCode() + " :: Skin created for the label : " + grade);
                            });
                            labelPool.put(grade, lbl);
                        }
                        lbl.setText(grade + "(" + score + ")");
                        return lbl;
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        tableView.setItems(items);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        Button btn = new Button("Update Score");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            person.setScore(rnd.nextInt(11));
        });

        Button refresh = new Button("Refresh Table to start from scratch");
        refresh.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            tableView.refresh();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(btn, refresh, tableView);
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Label In TableCell");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private String getCellCode() {
        return "Cell-" + this.hashCode();
    }
}
```

***Side Note:***

*Considering my actual requirement of multiple labels, it may be tricky to get the labels from the pool and call the applyCss on each new Label. So I am adding a one time listener to the sceneProperty of Label, to call the applyCss().*

```
Label label = new Label();
final InvalidationListener sceneListener = new InvalidationListener() {

    @Override
    public final void invalidated(final Observable observable) {
        // This is a one time listener to applyCss when rendered in scengraph for first time
        label.sceneProperty().removeListener(this);
        label.applyCss();
    }
};
label.sceneProperty().addListener(sceneListener);
```